# How to make compiler not show int to void pointer cast warnings

Tags: c, gcc, void-pointers

I have some code that does lots of casting from int to void* and vice-versa (i don't care if it's ugly. I like having generic stuff)

Example:

```
typedef struct _List {
    long size;
    long mSize; // Max size
    void** elementArray;
}List;

List l;
...
int i = 2;
l.elementArray[i] = i; // Intentional usage of pointer as integer
// Actual size of pointer does not matter
```

but when i compile i get a bajillion

```
 warning: cast to 'void *' from smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-void-pointer-cast]
```

warnings.
Is there a flag to tell gcc to not print this specific warning?

I'm compiling with -Wall, so I'm not sure if i can make this go away that easilly

Comment: Use `uintptr_t` instead.

Comment: Also, your example does not show any pointer casts.  The warning you're getting *may* be harmless, or it may be the only, ahem, warning you will receive before the program blows up in your face; without seeing the actual code at stake we can't tell.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

apparently just take the flag that the compiler gives you and slap a "no" in front of it does the trick!

```
-Wno-int-to-void-pointer-cast
```

Comment: Yes, that is what that is there for.  But I would be very hesitant to just slap that switch on there... this particular warning is *very often* indicative of real, honest-to-Ghod, you-can't-do-that-that-way-it-will-explode bugs.

Comment: I already have a debug make that doesn't ignore warnings. Chill.

Comment: This is imo not a good solution, because it doesn't solve the possible issue, it only makes the compiler ignore it.
Also it turns the switch off globally for the whole program, which might cause problems elsewhere in the code.

Comment: My question was how to make the compiler not show the flags. Not how to fix the flags. I am well aware of what I am doing in the code and I chose to ignore it.

Comment: take the flag out is just a way to hide possible issue... it is to solve the issue not to bury it deeper...

Answer (score 40):

For the sake of others who are possibly looking for an answer like me:

If you want to not add an extra compilation flag due to the fact that you might be upcasting an int to a void* accidentally somewhere else, you can use the following snippet to force a cast from an int to a void* where you are sure you want it to happen and then the compiler won't bug you about the cast:

```
#define INT2VOIDP(i) (void*)(uintptr_t)(i)
```

Of course be sure to include stdint.h, so then you can do the following:

```
void *val = INT2VOIDP(5);
```

Comment: Just realized this is like what Quig posted, ah well... If you don't want any + characters mine is here ;P

Answer (score 18):

you might want to use 'size_t'.

For example, if you have int i and void *a,

`i = (void *) a;` will give you that warning

to avoid this add size_t

`i = (void *) (size_t) a;`

Comment: The best answer, useful on both Win32 and x64

Answer (score 4):

In some cases doing this would be desired (eg. for the last pointer parameter of glVertexAttribPointer in OpenGL). You should be able to avoid the warning by doing something like this:

```
#define BUFFER_OFFSET(i) ((char*)NULL+(i))
myFunction(BUFFER_OFFSET(3));
```

Comment: #define BUFFER_OFFSET(X) ((const GLvoid *) (std::uintptr_t) (X))

Answer (score 0):

The warning is telling you that ints are narrower than pointers, so you are losing information when you cast from a pointer to an int. As suggested above, use uintptr_t. That is an integer type that is as wide as a pointer. If you are forced to use int, then you are SOL.  "Generic" == broken.

Comment: He is casting from int to void* instead of the inverse.

Comment: Fine.  `int`s are still narrower than pointers, so the compiler has no way to fill in the missing bits.  Also, I presume that the pointer didn't start out as an `int`, so they must be a place somewhere else where a pointer is being cast to an `int`.